# Xamarin.iOS : ZXing scanner Gives Unhandled Exception on disposed

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Using the ZXing BarcodeScanner Crossplatform Library I created the Below code to scan the barcode which will return the scanned text result.

```
async static public Task<String> Scan()    
{
    var scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner
    {
        TopText = "Hold the camera up to the barcode\nAbout 6 inches away",
        BottomText = "Wait for the barcode to automatically scan!"
    };

    try
    {
        //This will start scanning
        ZXing.Result result = await scanner.Scan();
        string output = result.Text;
        scanner.Cancel();
        return output;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        scanner.Cancel();
        return null;
    }
}
```

It works well on Android.
But in iOS it throws a error while disposing as follows.

```
Unhandled Exception:

System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'ZXingScannerViewController'. occurred
```

This happens When `scanner.Cancel()` is hit in iOS.

Any Solution Why this happens in iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call `scanner.Cancel()` manually. Refer to [official usage](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile)

`MobileBarcodeScanner` has been disposed after you click the cancel button, so the app will crash if you call it again.

Comment: thats right but that happens only in iOS.
in Android you may need to use `scanner.Cancel()` inorder to come out of the scanner application once its scanned.

Comment: you can use macro `#if __ANDROID__
 scanner.Cancel();
   #endif`

Comment: Thanks for your time..
I already got the solution.
we can use xamarin **device library** to identify the platform
``if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
                {
                    scanner.Cancel();
                }``